# What are the consequences of using nuclear weapons against pirates or barbarians?

Tags: freeciv

What is the effect of using nuclear weapons against pirates or barbarians? Will the pirates or barbarians become more aggressive towards me? Will the other AI players like me less even though I am only attacking pirates or barbarians (a common enemy of all human and AI players)?